# force module install with CPAN

Tags: perl

I know it's easy to install a module with 'force' using CPAN from command prompt. I am trying to achieve same through the script:

```
use CPAN;
eval "use Filesys::DiskSpace" or do {
    CPAN::install("Filesys::DiskSpace");
};
```

Is there any way to add the option 'force' to the code?
I am having the following error while compiling the module:

```
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

The warnings could not be serious, so I would like to proceed with the installation.
Thanks.

Comment: If you are attempting to [automatically install missing modules from CPAN](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8183293), don't do it! Instead declare the dependencies, see examples in http://stackoverflow.com/a/7664993 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/2606677.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as you Really Know What You Are Doing:

```
eval "use Filesys::DiskSpace; 1" or do {
    CPAN::Shell->force("install","Filesys::DiskSpace");
};
```

The `use` builtin doesn't return anything useful, even when it is successful, so it is necessary to include the "`;1`" in the string eval.

Comment: It's working, but CPAN ask 'Would you like me to configure as much as possible automatically?' and I need to type 'yes'. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you'll need to instantiate `CPAN` to a variable and call the `force()` method on it

```
my $cpan = CPAN->new;
$cpan->force();
$cpan->install("Filesys::DiskSpace");
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are only making sure that [`Filesys::DiskSpace`](http://p3rl.org/Filesys%3a%3aDiskSpace) is installed:

```
unless( eval { require Filesys::DiskSpace } ){
  require CPAN;
  CPAN::Shell->force("install","Filesys::DiskSpace");
}
```

If you want to make sure that [`Filesys::DiskSpace`](http://p3rl.org/Filesys%3a%3aDiskSpace) is loaded, and install it if it's not available:

```
BEGIN{
  unless( eval { require Filesys::DiskSpace } ){
    require CPAN;
    CPAN::Shell->force("install","Filesys::DiskSpace");
  }
}
use Filesys::DiskSpace;
```

---

#### NOTE:

If you are having problems with your Perl programs working, it is probably because you just installed a broken module.

That particular module hasn't had an official release since 1999.
It also has a fair number of [bug reports](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Filesys-DiskSpace):

- It apparently [doesn't work on 64bit systems](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=18809).
- It doesn't work on [modern freebsd systems](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=34906).
- There are also file-systems that it doesn't support.