# Is there a simplest way to build perl package

Tags: perl, ubuntu, build

I wrote a few Perl libraries(.pm) and Perlscripts(.pl) on Ubuntu and I need to distribute them to my colleagues in my office. Those scripts and libraries require third party libraries. I want to make it very simple.

Infomation about me.

- I know how to create a Perl script.
- I know how to create bash file.
- I have no experience in creating MAKE file, rpm, Deb etc.

Comment: If you colleagues all have Ubuntu (preferably same version) and there are enough of them, it could be worthwhile to learn how to build a `*.deb` package.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I don't want to make it specific. They are either linux or Mac users

Comment: Have you read [Module::Build](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-Build/lib/Module/Build.pm)?

Comment: @Konerak, I haven't tried it yet. Is it the simplest way? At first, I thought rpm is the simplest but I stuck with many different version of 'howto'. So I decided to ask experts here.

Comment: @Konerak, actually, I did pass that kind of page for several times while I was trying to learn this stuffs on my own before I asked this question. My main problem is I only saw 

Standard process for building & installing modules:

  perl Build.PL
  ./Build
  ./Build test
  ./Build install

but don't know where to create this make file and how to let it know my script

Comment: @JessadaThutkawkorapin - Creating the makefile is what `Makefile.PL` does.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd recommend using [`Module::Starter`](http://search.cpan.org/~xsawyerx/Module-Starter-1.58/lib/Module/Starter.pm) to set up a template for each module.  Once it's installed, you can call `module-starter` from the command line, eg:

```
module-starter --module=My::Module --author="Jessada Thutkawkorapin" --email=your@email.com
```

or, if you want a distribution with multiple modules:

```
module-starter --distro=Foo --module=Foo,Foo::Bar,Foo::Baz --author="Jessada Thutkawkorapin" --email=your@email.com
```

Then, just overwrite the `.pm` files with your modules, include any unit tests that you want to run (the default tests basically check the syntax of the module along with the pod syntax).  A basic installation of the modules is then done via

```
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
make install
```

(technically, `make test` is optional, but it's highly recommended).

Now, if these modules rely on other CPAN modules, then you can use the module [`CPAN`](http://search.cpan.org/~andk/CPAN-1.9800/lib/CPAN.pm) to install them, eg:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CPAN;

#populate however you'd like, either hard-coded, read from a file, etc.
my @modules_to_install=(); 

foreach(@modules_to_install)
{
  CPAN::Shell->install($_);
}
```

So, you can distribute a zip/tarball/etc with the folders and files that `module-starter` started (and that you modified) along with the above script to install any CPAN dependencies, and call it, say, `cpan_install.pl`.  If you want, you can then wrap everything up in a final script called, say, `install.pl` that does all of these things.

Comment: Prabably, my main problem here is that how and where can I specific the location of my script? All my script are under <project>/bin and my .pm are under <project>/bin/lib

Comment: Well, for each module (and for the distro, if you use the `--distro` option), `module-starter` includes `lib` and `t` directories, along with some other boilerplate that you can mostly ignore.  Once the modules are installed (via `perl Makefile.PL;make;make test;make install`), then they're installed into the `site_perl` subdirectory of whatever Perl distribution you're using.

Comment: Downvote for [invoking CPAN yourself to install missing modules](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8183293). Instead declare the dependencies with [`PREREQ_PM`](https://metacpan.org/module/ExtUtils::MakeMaker#PREREQ_PM) so they end up in the distro meta file, also see examples in http://stackoverflow.com/a/7664993 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/2606677.

Answer (score 2):

My usual method these days is to simply copy a `Build.PL` file from one of my existing distributions, and go from there. Obviously that's not a useful strategy for the first one, but CPAN is full of thousands of these files.

For a simple single-`.pm` file pure-perl distribution it's probably easiest to start by copying someone else's `Build.PL` file and edit the fields as appropriate for your case. Likely all you should need to change are the `module_name` and `requires` fields.

Here's a simple one of mine you can steal^W be inspired by:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Module::Build;

my $build = Module::Build->new(
   module_name => 'Your::Name::Here',
   requires => {
      'Your::Requirements::Here' => '1.23',
   },
   build_requires => {
      'Test::More' => 0,
   },
   license => 'perl',
   create_makefile_pl => 'traditional',
   create_license => 1,
   create_readme  => 1,
);

$build->create_build_script;
```

These fields, in order, mean:

- The name of the primary module in the distribution - this is where the name of the distribution itself is taken from, as well as its version and abstract summary
- Other modules that this distribution will depend on to build or run
- Other modules that this distribution will depend on to build, but won't be required once it's installed (typically this will be `Test::` modules or other build tools)
- The licencing terms applied to the distribution
- Create a legacy `Makefile.PL` for older CPAN clients that do not understand the `Build.PL` protocol
- Create a `LICENSE` file automatically from the declared licencing terms above
- Create a `README` file automatically by turning the main module's POD documentation into plaintext