# Trying to use eval to check for a perl module

Tags: perl, eval

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check if I have a Perl module before using it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251694/how-can-i-check-if-i-have-a-perl-module-before-using-it)

I'd like to eval a use statement similar to this: eval {use $foo;} but am having trouble with the correct syntax. I've tried various combinations of string interpolation, but the eval always succeeds even for a module that does not exist. Can someone give me hand with this one?

Comment: I'm not sure how `eval` is succeeding; I get a syntax error when using a variable with `use`. From `perldoc -f use`: "[use Module LIST] is exactly equivalent to BEGIN { require Module; import Module LIST; } except that Module *must* be a bare word."

Comment: Define "eval always succeeds".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idiom you are looking for is:

```
eval "use $module; 1" or ... ;

eval "use $module; 1" or warn "$module is not available: $@";
eval "use $module; 1" or die "This script requires $module";
eval "use $module; 1" or $module_available = 0;
```

`eval` "always succeeds" in the sense that program execution will continue no matter what code is evaluated -- that's really the whole point of an `eval` statement. If the evaluated string contained errors -- run time or compile time -- the return value of the `eval` call is `undef` and the special variable `$@` will be set with an appropriate error message.

The `use` statement, even when successful, does not return a value. That's why this idiom includes the "`; 1`" at the end.

Comment: Thanks, I just worked my way to this before checking if someone had submitted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`use` is a keyword that is processed during compilation, as is mentioned in the comments, it does require you to use bareword arguments. That is, no variables.

Now, I can't get an `eval { use $foo }` to even compile, because it causes a syntax error, so the script is never run. I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "always succeeds", unless you mean the opposite: "always fails".