# Perl - eval not trapping "use" statement

Tags: perl

I want to detect when a user is missing a required module and print a friendly error message explaining what they need to install.

So far I tried putting this at the beginning of my script:

```
eval {
    use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw(gunzip $GunzipError) ;
};
if ($@) {
    die "Error: IO::Uncompress::Gunzip not installed: $@";
}
```

But Perl seems to die on the "use" line instead of the "die" line and never prints my error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if I have a Perl module before using it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251694/how-can-i-check-if-i-have-a-perl-module-before-using-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening here is that the module is being `use`d at compile-time, regardless of the fact that it is inside the `eval` block.

This is also why [naab's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11020970/133939) to change from `eval BLOCK` form to `eval EXPR` form works as well; the expression is evaluated at run-time.
Changing the `use` to `require` will attempt to load the module at run-time:

```
eval {
    require IO::Uncompress::Gunzip;
    IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->import( qw/gunzip $GunzipError/ ) ;
};
if ($@) {
    die "Error: IO::Uncompress::Gunzip not installed: $@";
}
```

**Output**

> Error: IO::Uncompress::Gunzip not installed: Can't locate IO/Uncompress/Gunzip.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at - line 2.

Comment: There's no need to move the loading to run-time, and you don't want to move the loading to run-time. If you do, you'll get strict errors accessing `$GunzipError`.

Comment: @ikegami : Works for me (it's been `qw//`-ed)

Comment: Then your test is broken. `Global symbol "$GunzipError" requires explicit package name at -e line 1` is received from `perl -e'use strict; eval { require IO::Uncompress::Gunzip; IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->import( qw/gunzip $GunzipError/ ); }; die $@ if $@; $GunzipError;'`

Comment: (You would also have problems if `gunzip` had a prototype, but it doesn't.)

Comment: @ikegami : Do you mean to say that wrapping your test in a `BEGIN` block would render `$GunzipError` defined or exempt from strictures?

Comment: That would import `$GunzipError` at compile-time, and strict allows you to use imported variables.

Comment: @ikegami : Perhaps I'm doing something wrong here, but it doesn't work for me: `$ perl -we 'use strict; BEGIN { eval { require IO::Uncompress::Gunzip; IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->import( qw/gunzip $GunzipError/ ); }; die $@ if $@; $GunzipError; }'`

Comment: `Global symbol "$GunzipError" requires explicit package name at -e line 1.
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at -e line 1.`

Comment: Your "}" is misplaced. You shouldn't be putting the BEGIN around teh whole script. :) `perl -we 'use strict; BEGIN { eval { require IO::Uncompress::Gunzip; IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->import( qw/gunzip $GunzipError/ ); }; die $@ if $@; } $GunzipError;'`

Answer (score 11):

```
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw( gunzip $GunzipError );
```

is short for

```
BEGIN {
   require IO::Uncompress::Gunzip;
   import IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw( gunzip $GunzipError );
}
```

and `BEGIN` blocks are evaluated as soon as they are compiled. That means your code does:

1. Compilation phase:

   1. Compile `eval` statement.

      1. Compiled `BEGIN` block.

         1. Compile `require IO::Uncompress::Gunzip;`
         2. Compile `import IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw( gunzip $GunzipError );`
      2. Evaluate `BEGIN` block.

         1. **Evaluate `require IO::Uncompress::Gunzip;`**
         2. Evaluate `import IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw( gunzip $GunzipError );`
   2. Compile `if` statement.
2. Run phase:

   1. **Evaluate (empty)  `eval` statement.**
   2. Evaluate `if` statement.

If an exception happens in step 1.1.2.1, the `eval` run in step 2.1 won't catch it!

---

Solutions:

You started with something equivalent to

```
BEGIN {
   require IO::Uncompress::Gunzip;
   import IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw( gunzip $GunzipError );
}
```

It's errors from `require` you want to catch, so just add an `eval` around the `require`:

```
BEGIN {
   eval { require IO::Uncompress::Gunzip }
      or die "Error: IO::Uncompress::Gunzip not installed: $@";

   import IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw( gunzip $GunzipError );
}
```

You could also delay the `use` getting compiled (and thus evaluated) by using `eval EXPR` instead of `eval BLOCK`:

```
BEGIN {
   eval 'use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw( gunzip $GunzipError ); 1'
      or die "Error: IO::Uncompress::Gunzip not installed: $@";
}
```

(I wish there was a good way of finding out if a module is installed. Even the first solution will catch other errors, the second even more.)

Answer (score 0):

check out Class::Load's try_load_class ([CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Class-Load-0.20/lib/Class/Load.pm))

```
use Class::Load;
die "Error: IO::Uncompress::Gunzip not installed" if 
    (! try_load_class (IO::Uncompress::Gunzip));
```

But as far as I can tell, you can't import qw(gunzip $GunzipError) with Class::Load.