# perl module eval issues with qw

Tags: perl, module, require

I'm trying to give a "human readable message" for an application if there's missing modules upon running the script. However I've stumbled upon an issue when it comes to loading modules with qw.

I've tried the following:

```
use strict;
...
if ( ! eval { require Proc::Daemon;1; } ) {
    push (@install_packages, "Proc::Daemon"); 
} else {
    Proc::Daemon->import(qw( SOCK_STREAM SOMAXCONN ));
}
```

However it fails

```
Bareword "SOCK_STREAM" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./revmon.pl line 144.
Bareword "SOMAXCONN" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./revmon.pl line 144.
```

Using use obviously doesn't work as it will give the normal error-message

```
Can't locate Proc/Daemon.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .)
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./revmon.pl line 11.
```

Adding * to the bareword doesn't help much either since it's only used once which will throw another error with use warnings;

Is there same way to work around this to get the BAREWORDS working properly when the module can be loaded successfully?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What Perl version/platform are you on? Does it work if you call `Proc::Daemon->import("SOCK_STREAM","SOMAXCONN")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you load the module after you compile the code that uses it. When you do that, you can't use functions imported from the module as barewords.

---

Using `SOCK_STREAM()` and `SOMAXCONN()` will postpone the check to run-time.

Or

```
BEGIN {
    if ( eval { require Proc::Daemon } ) {
        Proc::Daemon->import(qw( SOCK_STREAM SOMAXCONN ));
    } else {
        push(@install_packages, "Proc::Daemon"); 
        *SOCK_STREAM = sub () { die };
        *SOMAXCONN   = sub () { die };
    }
}
```

Or move the stuff using Proc::Daemon to its own module

```
if ( eval { require Proc::Daemon } ) {
        require App::Proc::Daemon;
        $handler = App::Proc::Daemon->new();
    } else {
        push(@install_packages, "Proc::Daemon"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: @ysth, oops, was suppose to be a prototype. Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

For `use` at run-time, use string-eval, not block-eval, because any `use` statement encountered at compile-time will be evaluated at compile-time

```
if (! eval "use Proc::Daemon qw(SOCK_STREAM SOMAXCONN); 1") { ... }
```

Related questions:

[How can I check if I have a Perl module before using it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/251694/168657)

[Perl - eval not trapping "use" statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020911)

Comment: Not gonna help. Executes exactly the same at exactly the same time as it did before.