# What does this line mean in perl?

Tags: perl

I'm looking at some code, but I don't understand what the following line is doing/checking:

```
return if !%Foo::Details:: ;
```

What exactly is this doing?  Is it checking for the existence of module Foo::Details?

Comment: Looks like a really poor way of testing whether a module has been loaded into the symbol table. `%Foo::Details` is the symbol table entry for the package `Foo::Details`, if it isn't loaded it will return false, which when negated returns true. Take a look at [`the symbol table section of perlmod`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Symbol-Tables)

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I think it's elegant, solely based on its compactness. What exactly makes it poor?

Comment: It isn't very clear (at first) what this piece of code is doing, that is why I think it's *poor*. There are better, more readable, solutions.

Comment: Why does it have two colons on the end (`Foo::Details::` rather than `Foo::Details`)?  Is that just the syntax?

Comment: @Nosrettap The first sentence of the page I linked answers that question.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Thanks! If you put your comment in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Re "`%Foo::Details` is the symbol table entry for the package", That should be `%Foo::Details::`.

Comment: @ikegami yes, I realized I left it off a few minutes ago, but am outside of the edit comment window :|

Comment: @HunterMcMillen alright, I was just curious if it was horribly inefficient or something like that.

Comment: @Jarmund, a reason it's a poor way of checking whether a module is loaded is that `%Foo::Bar::` will evaluate to true if module "Foo::Bar::Baz" is loaded **even if "Foo::Bar" is not loaded!**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A hash in scalar context returns false if it's empty, so your code returns an empty list if the hash `%Foo::Details::` is empty.

That hash is the symbol table for the `Foo::Details` namespace. If a package variable or sub is created in the `Foo::Details` namespace, a glob corresponding to the name of the variable or sub will be created in `%Foo::Details::`. So, it returns an empty list if the Foo::Details namespace is empty.

```
$ cat >Foo/Details.pm
package Foo::Details;
sub boo { }
1;

$ perl -E'say %Foo::Details:: ?1:0;'
0

$ perl -E'use Foo::Details; say %Foo::Details:: ?1:0;'
1
```

It might be trying to check if the Foo::Details module has been loaded, but it's not perfect. For example, it will think Foo::Details has been loaded even if only Foo::Details::Bar has been loaded. To check if Foo::Details has been loaded, it might be better to check if `$INC{"Foo/Details.pm"}` is true. The problem with that approach is that it won't find "inlined modules".

Answer (score 3):

This code tests whether or not a module has been loaded. `%Foo::Details::` is the symbol table for the module `Foo::Details`.

If `Foo::Details` was never loaded `%Foo::Details::` will return false (because it contains no elements), which when negated with `!` will return true and return from whatever function you are in.

You can read more about symbol tables in [`perlmod#Symbol Tables`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Symbol-Tables)

Also, [`here is another SO post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251694/how-can-i-check-if-i-have-a-perl-module-before-using-it) that talks about ways to determine if a module was loaded.

Comment: more correct to say %Foo::Details:: *is* the symbol table for the module

Comment: Isn't it technically an entry? Since it is held in `%main::`?

Comment: Each element of %Foo::Details:: is an entry. %Foo::Details:: contains the entries for the Foo::Details namespace, which is to say it's the symbol table for Foo::Details.

Comment: the symbol table *entry* for Foo::Details is `$Foo::{'Details::'}` (which is a glob that contains %Foo::Details:: in its hash slot).