# How to check whether Data::Dumper is installed?

Tags: perl, data-dumper

I am new to Perl. I have a Perl script which uses the [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) module. But on some systems the module isn't installed. So I need to check whether `Data::Dumper` is installed or not. How can I do that?

Comment: [How can I check if I have a Perl module before using it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251694/how-can-i-check-if-i-have-a-perl-module-before-using-it)

Comment: This was hastily classified as a duplicate. The link has a case of somebody wanting to *conditionally* include a module, where this one could be about the frequent command line I use to do the same thing: `perl -MData::Dumper -e 1` It seems a waste to write evals if you can check it from a simple command line.

Comment: `Data::Dumper` is a core perl module. It will be part of any perl installation:

$ corelist Data::Dumper

Data for 2015-02-14
Data::Dumper was first released with perl 5.005

You can't not have it. :)