# How to check if perl module is available?

Tags: perl, module, namespaces, package

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251694/how-can-i-check-if-i-have-a-perl-module-before-using-it/251786#251786):

```
my $rc = eval
{
  require Term::ReadKey;
  Term::ReadKey->import();
  1;
};

if($rc)
{
  # Term::ReadKey loaded and imported successfully
  ...
}
```

But that does not work for packages defined inside other modules like:

```
{
  package Hi::Test;
}    

my $rc =  eval{ require Hi::Test };
```

`$rc` is false here.

How can I check that 'Hi::Test' is available?

Comment: Yup i got it..removing my comments

Comment: Different way to check that `Class` was loaded and available: https://github.com/mojolicious/mojo/blob/master/lib/Mojo/Loader.pm#L47

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like `defined(*Hi::Test::)`, except that simply mentioning `*Hi::Test::` creates the package.

```
$ perl -E'
   say defined(*Hi::Test::) ? "exists" : "doesn'\''t exist";
'
exists
```

By using symbolic references, you avoid that problem.

```
$ perl -E'
   { package Hi::Test }
   say defined(*{"Hi::Test::"}) ? "exists" : "doesn'\''t exist";
   say defined(*{"Hi::TEST::"}) ? "exists" : "doesn'\''t exist";
'
exists
doesn't exist
```

Putting that code in a sub to makes things cleaner.

```
$ perl -E'
   use strict;
   use warnings;

   sub test_for_package {
      my ($pkg_name) = @_;
      $pkg_name .= "::";
      return defined(*$pkg_name);
   }

   { package Hi::Test }
   say test_for_package("Hi::Test") ? "exists" : "doesn'\''t exist";
   say test_for_package("Hi::TEST") ? "exists" : "doesn'\''t exist";
'
exists
doesn't exist
```

Note that creating the package `Foo::Bar::Baz` also creates the packages `Foo` and `Foo::Bar`.

Comment: There seems a bug in perl when `eval 'require Some::Pkg'` which spoil global namespace. https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=126077

Comment: @Eugen Konkov, Yes, as mentioned, referencing `Some::Pkg` creates the package, so `require Some::Pkg` creates the package, even if it eventually throws an exception.

Comment: @Eugen Konkov, Interesting. `no strict qw( refs );` is indeed not required. Fixed.

Comment: I think that is due to 'defined' which does not produce error

Comment: It does seem to be. That's *very* interesting once you realize that `defined` is only called after the strict error would have been thrown. That means they went out of their way to support this by treating it specially in the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming there is actually something happening in that package, and not just an empty block.

The following code checks if there are any entries in the symbol table for that package. It's dirty, but it works as long as there are subs or package variables registered.

```
{
  package Hi::Test;

  sub foo;
}

my $rc =  eval{ require Hi::Test };
if (! $rc) {
  $rc = do {
    no strict;
    *stash = *{"Hi::Test::"};
    scalar keys %stash;
  }
}

print $rc;
```

It will print `1`.

Comment: `defined(*{"Hi::Test::"})` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little rusty on this, but I think your `require` will be failing regardless - this errors:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

{
    package Hi::Test;

    sub foo {
        print "bar\n";
    }
}

{
    package main;
    require Hi::Test; 
}
```

This errors - it can't find it `@INC` (because it isn't in `@INC`). Both `use` and `require` specifically tell `perl` to "go out and find a module file"

But you can still call 'foo' with:

```
Hi::Test::foo();
```

So you can't test the loading of the module with `eval` nor can you check `%INC` .

But what you can do is check `%Hi::`:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%Hi::;
print Dumper \%Hi::Test::;
```

Which gives us:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Test::' => *{'Hi::Test::'}
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'foo' => *Hi::Test::foo
        };
```

So we can:

```
print "Is loaded" if defined $Hi::{'Test::'}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**
I have found this clue:

```
my $module =  *main::;
my @sub_name =  split '::', $full_name;
while( each @sub_name ) {
    $module =  $$module{ $sub_name[$_].'::' };
}
print "Module is available"   if $module;
```

In compare to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32608860/4632019) answer it does not create additional variable in global stash

Comment: Please attribute where you have found that.

Comment: this can be found in `perlmod` - each package has a magic hash called `%packagename::`  So you can do `print Dumper \%main::` - or in this example: `print Dumper \$main::{'Hi::'};` giving `$VAR1 = \*{'::Hi::'};`. What you _can't_ do is: `print Dumper \$main::{'Hi::Test::'};`

Comment: `%::`, `%main::`, `%main::main::` and `%main::main::main::` are all the same namespace. I'd drop the `main` from your code.